# How to spy on a nodejs process

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I'm running a nodejs script that's taking a long time. It runs a very long for loop and does some calculations. At the end it will display the answer. The answer is probably not 42 but a 5 digit number. I removed the console.log messages that displays what it's doing to make it run faster.

I'm wondering how far it's gotten. Is there any way to peek into the process and see how far in the loop it is, or what values are contained within any of the variables? I don't want to have to interrupt it because I ran it with the time command to calculate how long it took to get the answer.

It took about 9 minutes to finish when it looped 1 billion times. How long do you think it will take to finish looping 1 trillion times?

Comment: What the hell are you trying to calculate? If it took 9 minutes to loop one billion times, it should in theory take 150 hours to loop one trillion times.

Comment: The last 5 digits of the factorial of 1 trillion.

Comment: I can't imagine anything you do being faster than `console.log`.

Comment: How is console.log helpful here if the program is already running?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom [repl](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) and expose it via a socket from your node program. Then you can telnet into your process and you will have access to any global variables as well as any that you expose to the repl context. For example:

```
var net = require("net")
  , repl = require("repl");

var counterOfInterest = 0;
setInterval(function() { counterOfInterest++; }, 1000);
function whatsTheStatus() { 
  return 'process has counted ' + counterOfInterest + ' times'
};

net.createServer(function (socket) {
  var remote = repl.start("remote ➜  ", socket);
  remote.context.whatsTheStatus = whatsTheStatus;
}).listen(8888);
```

Then, you can telnet into your repl and interact with your node program!

```
$ telnet 127.0.01  8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
remote ➜  whatsTheStatus()
'process has counted 9 times'
remote ➜  whatsTheStatus()
'process hascounted 12 times'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up node-inspector and use a break point.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very old, but I just want to add something.

Firstly, Using Node.js for such a CPU intensive task is not recommended. You should use a more low-level or compiled language like C or Java. You'll see a hell lot of improvement in performance.

If you anyways do it in Node.js, may be you can `console.log` conditionally, i.e. after every million or so, like this.

```
if (counter % 1000000 == 0) {
    console.log('Progress: ' + counter);
}
```